# Monorepo pattern for two different angular applications?

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster, nrwl-nx

Until now we had a single angular 8 application. But now we have to create a new admin app whose UI would be similar to the existing application (similar UI as in similar login component, sidebar, navbar, etc). Since these two applications would be deployed on two different servers but sharing components with each other, we decided to keep two different source codes under one repo with a shared component library.

Our existing application is generated using [Jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/).

**Following two approaches I found could be useful for maintaining two different applications.**

I read the article at [Creating Libraries for Angular](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries). However, I could not find any material on how to change the existing build process to build two different applications? All the articles I read had Angular CLI commands to build different applications. Since we already have webpack as a bundler, how do I configure it to build both of my applications? Basically all my doubts were regarding how to extend the existing tools that we are using to build, test and maintain these two different applications.

Then I read about monorepo pattern and came across [Nx](https://nx.dev/angular/getting-started/what-is-nx) by [nrwl.io](https://nrwl.io). As far as I understood its a wrapper on top of angular CLI to support monorepo pattern and comes with all the tools I would need to maintain both applications.

So my question is, Is monorepo pattern worth going for when you only have to share code between two applications? This is in terms of the ease of development vs the time it would take to convert the existing application to support monorepo pattern (setting up tooling as there is in [Nx](https://nx.dev/angular/getting-started/what-is-nx)) which I have read is a bit of a headache.

Comment: Please note that the webpack build process generated by JHipster is not fully compatible with angular-cli, so I doubt Nx would work. The shared library looks good to me, you would have 3 folders: lib, app1 and app2. Your lib builmd proccess should deploy to your local npm registry (e.g.. Sonatype Nexus) and the 2 apps should refer to it in their respective package.json

Comment: Agreed that JHipster webpack build process is not fully compatible with angular-cli. However with the approach of publishing library to local npm registry I would have overhead of managing versions for library and updating in both apps. This overhead seems to be taken care by monorepo pattern as showed in Nx guide.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm a huge fan of NX.

### How can you change existing build process to build two different applications?

Not sure if I can verify this next statement, but in the past, I believe the Angular docs were worded around single applications. More recently (v7 or 8) the documentation vocabulary has been updated around [Workspaces](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#workspace-and-project-file-structure). Possibly due to NX's growing popularity (they've been pioneering Angular monorepo development since pre Angular 6) ?

**Out of the box Angular CLI**

Since you're using Angular 8, you can generate applications just like you would generate a component with the Angular CLI: `ng generate application admin-app`. Also, `ng build` accepts an application name as a parameter, so this is all you need to be able to build two separate applications with the Angular CLI out of the box. `ng build public-app` and `ng build admin-app`

However, the codebase could get very disorganized if you did this in a pre-existing application (AKA an app that is generated with `ng new`), because the new app would get placed in a `projects` directory inside the codebase. You'd basically end up with App-Ception, which I think is a terrible idea.

There is [official guidance around setting up a multi project workspace](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects). You basically create an empty workspace, and all generated apps get placed inside the projects directory.

### **Is monorepo pattern worth going for when you only have to share code between two applications?**

This is subjective, and there are pros and cons to both approaches (monorepo vs poly/microrepo) but in my opinion the answer is definitely yes. But I have to be honest, I would not even attempt it without NX.

**NX**

NX brings a lot to the table. Saying that it's wrapper around the Angular CLI is really only scratching the surface. It does have a collection of schematics that extend / improve upon existing Angular CLI schematics (`ng generate app|component|lib` etc.. is a schematic). It also makes it easy to incorporate better tooling out of the box (Jest > Karma; Cypress > Protractor). It also has its own CLI tool that addresses a lot of problems that monorepo structure introduces (have a look at their [guides](https://nx.dev/web/guides/monorepo-affected))

**Try incorporating it in your existing codebase**

Based on their [Getting Started Docs](https://nx.dev/angular/getting-started/getting-started#adding-to-an-existing-angular-cli-workspace), you can easily try it out just by doing:

`ng add @nrwl/workspace`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did go for Nx mainly because I believe I would have to make a lot of webpack config changes to support multiple application build. Just one question though, Nx has tslint as default linter and I would like to change it to eslint which I have already configured, where in angular.json file would I have to make changes to integrate that?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. I looked into this a bit, according to comments on this issue on the NX Github, this is something that will be implemented by the Angular CLI team (not the NX team): https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1912